# Tailwind breakpoints not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have created a ui library that uses and exports a tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    darkMode: 'class',
    important: true,
    content: ['./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
    theme: {
        extend: {
        },
        colors: {
            // primary colors
            white: '#FEFEFB',
            black: '#02020a',
            grey: '#ced4da',
            'dark-grey': '#6c757d',
            transparent: 'transparent',
            current: 'currentColor',
        }
    },
    plugins: [],
    variants: {
        extend: {
            dropShadow: ['hover'],
            grayscale: ['hover']
        }
    }
};
```

Now, I am using this tailwind config in a separate `Next.js` project like this:

```
import tailwindConfig from 'ck-ui/dist/tailwind.config';

module.exports = {
    ...tailwindConfig,
    theme: {
        ...tailwindConfig.theme,
        extend: {
            ...tailwindConfig.theme.extend,
            fontFamily: {
                heading: ['var(--font-heading)'],
                breath: ['var(--font-breath)']
            }
        }
    }
};
```

But I am facing weird outcomes in different projects I am using this tailwind config in:

In one case, one of my library component is rendering as expected (image below):
[image]

Now, when using the same config in a different project, I am seeing different results where the screen breakpoints don't work as expected (image below):
[image]

And now I am clueless about how to fix this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this in the "content" section of the tailwind.config.cjs file at the root of your directory?
`'./app/components/**/*.{erb,html}'`

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/rz1sx8/bug_related_to_view_components_and_tailwind/)

I was having a similar problem, where response to breakpoints was very erratic, and this fixed it for me!